# AWS can I view non-default VPC resources in the AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm experimenting with cloudformation to create resources like EC2 instances in a custom VPC.

I'm curious if you can change the aws console to use your new VPC and view/create/delete resources in the console.

Right now, I cannot see an option in the EC2 console to use anything but the default-VPC.

Is this even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have other VPCs created, then they will show up in the console. There are not any views in the AWS console that I'm aware of that limit the view to only the default VPC.

Comment: correct! i was been stupid. but thanks for helping me figure that out! :-)